# How to disable button using a role

Tags: php, roles

I want to disable a button using a role admin, this is my code.

```
<div class="footer-section">
<?php if($this->user->role !== 'admin' && $this->user->role !== 'worker') ?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-red col-md-6 flat-box-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddSale"><h5 class="text-bold"><?=label('PAY');?></h5></button>
</div>
```

It does not work, I use sales as the user and the button still showed, can some one help please

Comment: Are you trying to display the button in a disabled state, or are you trying to hide the button from being added to the page at all?

Comment: i'm trying to hide the button sir if the roles is not admin or worker

Comment: no sir, i'm using CodeIgniter

Comment: You said you want to hide the button if the role is not admin or worker but you're using And (`&&`) not Or in your code.

Comment: @j08691 i'm new with this sir, the code is <div class="footer-section">
<?php if($this->user->role !== 'admin' && $this->user->role !== 'worker') ?>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-red col-md-6 flat-box-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddSale"><h5 class="text-bold"><?=label('PAY');?></h5></button>
</div>

Comment: Hey, for adding button with php you should use echo method, inside script to insert html code with button. So change in html quote to double quote  and put all needed html into quote

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the button to users with an `admin` or `worker` role, change your condition to:

```
<?php if($this->user->role == 'admin' || $this->user->role == 'worker') {
    echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-red col-md-6 flat-box-btn' data-
    toggle='modal' data-target='#AddSale'>
    <h5 class='text-bold'>".label('PAY')."</h5>
    </button>";
}?>
```

Comment: Is it showing up even when you don't have the admin or worker role?

Comment: Yes sir.., it still showed. i try using staff role, the button still showed

Answer (score 0):

You need to `echo` the button in the `if` statement.

```
<div class="footer-section">
<?php 
    if($this->user->role !== 'admin' && $this->user->role !== 'worker') {
        echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-red col-md-6 flat-box-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddSale"><h5 class="text-bold">' . label('PAY') . '</h5></button>'
    }
?>
</div>
```

This only renders the button if the role is not *admin* and not *worker*.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="footer-section">
<?php if($this->user->role !== 'admin' && $this->user->role !== 'worker') 
echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-red col-md-6 flat-box-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddSale"><h5 class="text-bold">'.label("PAY").'</h5></button>';?>
</div>
```

Comment: i change the `<?php if($this->user->role !== 'admin' && $this->user->role !== 'worker') ` into `<?php if($this->user->role !== 'admin' && $this->user->role !== 'worker') ` and the rest using your code is running well, thank you sir